# How to get heat generation from the BTU C#

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I've been trying to use WMI classes to get the heat generation from the BTU, but to no avail.

```
public static ushort GetHeat()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new  ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT HeatGeneration FROM CIM_Chassis");
    ushort Heat = 0;

    foreach (ManagementObject HeatAmount in Searcher.Get())
    {
        Heat = (UInt16)HeatAmount["HeatGeneration"];
        break;
    }

    return Heat;
}
```

I get a NullReferenceException. How do I get the heat generation?

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that this particular property is not available on the hardware you're testing.  It might return on a different hardware profile.

If you check one of the more reliable properties, such as "ChassisType" or "Manufacturer", you'll probably see that the searcher is indeed working the way it should.

Here are the properties that **may** be available that you can test with:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387204(v=vs.85).aspx

So, in whatever app you're writing, you'll probably have to account for "unavailable" values if the property comes back as null.  (By the way, it comes back as null on the mini-tower I'm currently testing code on too, but other properties I tested return as expected)

Comment: So... the code is right, but my hardware doesn't have a option for it?
Yes, chassis type, manufacturer, and others do show up. I'm writing an app to show all the info of the computer. It's a laptop, by the way.

Comment: Yes. I'd say the code is right. If it wasn't, we would see nulls getting returned for everything.  I believe some or most of those values are provided by the manufacturer/OEM.  So, there really isn't any sort of mandatory enforcement regarding whether they embed that information or not.